# Why does sscanf not work properly with a bool type

Tags: c++, c, boolean, scanf

The output of this code:

```
const char *buff = "*_2D 1";
char field[10];
int flag;
sscanf(buff, "%s %d", field, &flag);
printf("field:%s flag:%i\n", field, flag);
```

is  `field:*_2D flag:1`

However by changing the `int` to `bool` results in strange behaviour:

```
const char *buff = "*_2D 1";
char field[10];
bool flag;
sscanf(buff, "%s %d", field, &flag);
printf("field:%s flag:%i\n", field, flag);
```

The output is `field: flag:1`

Can anyone explain what is happening here? I would've thought the bool would be interpreted as an int, which it appears to be, but the rest of the string disappears.

Comment: Mixing C++ types with C IO function is a *bad* idea.

Comment: @ybungalobill: What C++ type?

Comment: @Salgar: it's also (an alias for) a C99 type. But you've tagged the question with both "C" and "C++"; which language are you actually using?

Comment: @Salgar: Old C or C99? C99 has it if you include stdbool.h

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Imagine if `bool` is only one byte, rather than the four (or even eight) that an `int` uses. Then telling `sscanf` that `&flag` is a pointer to an `int` will end up overwriting either three or seven bytes elsewhere on the stack -- which could be right on top of your `field` variable. That space would be filled with 0 bytes, effectively terminating your string.

Comment: You are correct, I hadn't realised `sizeof(bool)` on my platform was 1. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

`bool` is a separate type to `int`, and is likely to be a single byte (which on most common platforms is smaller than `int`).

`sscanf` is not type-safe; you are telling it (with the `%d` conversion specifier) that you are providing a pointer to an `int`, and so it assumes that it is safe to write an `int` there. If the actual type is smaller, then you'll get undefined behaviour; most likely, either other local variables will be overwritten, or the stack frame will be corrupted. In this case, it looks like it is overwriting the beginning of `field` with the zero-valued bytes of the integer value `1`.

Answer (score 3):

It could be because `sizeof(bool)` is sometimes `1` ? So, I don't know much C++, but in C that would be undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [spec for sscanf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/scanf.html), the description of %d is:

> > Matches an optionally signed decimal integer... In the absence of a size modifier, the application shall ensure that the corresponding argument is a pointer to int.

Also from the same spec,

> > if the result of the conversion cannot be represented in the space provided, the behavior is undefined.

Since sizeof(bool) < sizeof(int), you are in the dreaded Undefined Behavior zone, and anything can happen.

Answer (score 0):

The `sscanf` function failed because `bool` is not an `int` but a `char`

Try this one:

```
const char *buff = "*_2D 1";
char field[10];
char flag;
sscanf(buff, "%s %d", field, &flag);
printf("field:%s flag:%i\n", field, flag);
```

It'll give you the same error.

Comment: `bool` is not a `char` either; it's a distinct type (assuming this is either C++, or C99 with `<stdbool.h>`), and not guaranteed to be the same size as `char`.

Comment: ...is considere as a 'signed number of one bytes' (like char) for sscanf (in stdbool.h, _Bool is just a typedef)

Comment: @Asgar: no: in C99, `bool` is a macro that expands to `_Bool`; `_Bool` is a built-in type, distinct from `char`. In C++, `bool` is a built-in type, again distinct from `char`. The specification of `sscanf` (and `fscanf`, which it references) does not mention `bool` (or `_Bool`) at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++ (which appears to be the case from your comments), why not use C++ streams instead of the C-style `scanf` approach ?

```
const std::string buff = "*_2D 1";
std::string field;
bool flag = false;
std::istringstream ss(buff);
ss >> field >> flag;
std::cout << "field:" << field << " flag:" << flag << std::endl;
```

Comment: Indeed, unfortunately I didn't write this originally. Such is software.

Comment: @Salgar : I know all too well :)